# How to fix Windows 7 dual-boot after upgrade to 11.04?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, startupmanager

I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 working in prefect harmony on a dual boot system, where Win7 was the default OS. This was until I let Ubuntu upgrade itself to 11.04. Ever since that, the default OS is now Ubuntu. I entered Startup Manager from Ubuntu and changed the default to Win7, but still - effectively whenever I reboot Ubuntu starts up. When I enter Startup Manager again it seems as if Win7 is the default...

What should I do?

Comment: Have you got separate HDD for each OS? Are you using GRUB for boot? Include a photo/screenshot, and give more details!

Comment: have you looked at the questions over there? ----->

Comment: And you? He had no words about HDD, Grub. I can imagine the issue in min. 2 cases!

Answer (score 1):

If possible, edit the `/etc/default/grub` Grub2 configuration file manually and change the value at the GRUB_DEFAULT setting.

For details see the [Ubuntu Grub2 help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202).